# Running a daemonset on all nodes of a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

How can I run a daemonset on all nodes of a kubernetes cluster (including master) without overriding the taints of any nodes?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run a daemonset and make sure it will get scheduled onto all nodes in the cluster regardless of taints. For example in a GKE cluster running google’s Stackdriver logging agent the fluentd-gcp daemonset has the following toleration to make sure it gets past any node taint:

```
tolerations:
-operator: Exists
 effect: NoExecute
-operator: Exists
 effect: NoSchedule
```

This way you can scheduler the daemonset on the master even if it has `NoSchedule` taints.

Comment: thanks @Prafull Ladha . But my worker nodes dont have any taints. so the daemonset wont be scheduled on my worker nodes but only on master node if i use the above toleration.

Answer (score 3):

in my case it was:

```
tolerations:
- operator: Exists # matches all keys, values and effects which means this will tolerate everything
```

> An empty key with operator Exists matches all keys, values and effects
>   which means this will tolerate everything.
>
> ```
> tolerations:
> - operator: "Exists"
> ```

From: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#concepts